# Перезапись SASS/SCSS переменных при смене темы

Tags: css, sass, scss

Всем привет. Хочу перезаписывать значение переменных при смене темы. При смене темы применяется класс dark/light-theme к body. Есть файл с переменными и файл с темами. Хочу, чтобы при появлении класса дефолтные переменные заменялись новыми значениями.

variables.scss

```
$black: #222;
$white: #fff;
$lightGray: #ccc;
$orange: #e24545;
$mainFont: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

custom-theme.scss

```
// other logic for themes
.dark-theme {
     $black: #888; // ???
}
```